# Basic analysis question: under what conditions does $f(x) = f(y)$ imply $x = y$?

Tags: real-analysis

At first I thought invertible, if both $x$ and $y$ are within the domain over which $f$ is invertible.

However, I vaguely remember that there is a broader generalization than this which does not require invertibility. Could this statement be true merely when $f(x)$ is surjective?

Comment: This is just the definition of an injective function (also called a one-to-one function).

Comment: "*At first I thought invertible*" $\;-\;$ The actual condition is *injective*, as answered already. That's weaker than *invertible*, and is in fact equivalent to $f$ having a [left inverse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_function#Left_and_right_inverses).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It suffices to be injective. Let us elaborate a bit on the subject.

Let $f:X\to Y$ be a function. This means that, if $x\in X$, $y\in Y$ and $z\in Y$, one has that
\begin{align*}
\begin{cases}
(x,y)\in f\\\\
(x,z)\in f
\end{cases}\Rightarrow y = z
\end{align*}

Within such context, we say that $f$ is injective iff, for every $x\in X$ and $y\in X$, it is true that
\begin{align*}
f(x) = f(y) \Rightarrow x = y
\end{align*}

As you can see, it is precisely the property you are talking about.

It is worth reminding that it differs from the definition of function given above.

The first definition states that, for each element of the domain $X$, there is associated an unique element of the counter domain $Y$. The second statement says that different elements of the domain cannot have the same image.

Hopefully this helps !